# Show that $2 - \sqrt{2}$ is irrational

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, irrational-numbers

I suppose $2 - \sqrt{2} $ is rational.
so $$2- \sqrt{2} = {a/b} $$
where a,b are integers and gcd(a,b) = 1.

$$\text{Step 1. } 2 = (a/b)^2 \text{ //squared both sides }$$
$$\text{Step 2. } 2b^2 = a^2 \text{ //We see $a^2$ is even }$$
$$\text{Step 3. }2b^2 = (2k)^2$$
Step 3 since $a^2$ is even and so $a$ is even too. Also, k is an integer.
$$\text{Step 4. }b^2 = (2k)^2 \text{ //We see $b^2$ is even }$$
Step 4 since $b^2$ is even and so $b$ is even too.

We see $ a$ and $b$ are even. We see $gcd(a,b) \neq 1$

Is this proof correct ?

Comment: Suppose otherwise that $2-\sqrt{2}$ is rational.  Then as a rational number minus another rational number is rational, that would imply that $2-(2-\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$ is rational.  But then we're at our classical example and we know that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, so we are done.

Comment: It's the standard proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, but it's difficult to see how it pertains to $2 - \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: As for if your "attempt" is correct or not... you essentially copied the proof for that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.  But.... here you began with $2-\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}$ and then moments later wrote that $2=(\frac{a}{b})^2$ which is incorrect.  Instead, $(\frac{a}{b})^2 = (2-\sqrt{2})^2 = 6-4\sqrt{2}$, not $2$

Comment: Note that the sum of a rational number and an irrational number is irrational.

Comment: Sorry that was a stupid mistake on squaring both sides! Indeed I proved $\sqrt {2}$ is irrational, so this proof becomes very easy. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of Contradiction let us assume that  $2-\sqrt{2} \in \Bbb Q$ , say $2-\sqrt{2}=r \in \Bbb Q \implies \sqrt{2}= 2-r$ but since both $2,r \in \Bbb Q$ and $(\Bbb Q,+)$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb R,+)$ (i.e. basically addition of two rational numbers is rational) it follows that $\sqrt{2} \in \Bbb Q$ , a contradiction!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 of your proof is incorrect:

From:

$$2- \sqrt{2} = {a/b} $$

it does not follow that:

$$2 = (a/b)^2$$

but rather that:

$$(a/b)^2=(2- \sqrt{2})^2=4-4\sqrt{2}+2=6-4\sqrt{2}$$

Now, I am sure you want to know: so how *do* you prove it then?! Well, likely you will get many Answers that will show you how ... but your question was whether *your* proof was correct ... it is not.

Answer (score 1):

That proof is not correct.

You start with $2-\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}$ but on your next line you jump to $2=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2$.

What you instead want to do is show that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational (which seems like what you've done) then prove the following property: a rational minus an irrational number yields an irrational number. This can be done by considering the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), which states that if $p,q$ are rationals, then $p+q$ is rational. Here's a hint on how to prove this:

> Let $p=\frac{a}{b},q=\frac{c}{d}$. What is $p+q$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: There's no hint

Comment: Hover over it/click on it; it's a spoiler in case you want to think more about it yourself without getting spoiled on the solution

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate approach, note that $2-\sqrt 2$ is a root of $x^2-4x+2$ (the conjugate root is $2+\sqrt 2$ so just compute $(x-(2-\sqrt 2))(x-(2+\sqrt 2))$.

By the Rational Root Theorem, this quadratic has no rational roots.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another proof: $0<2-\sqrt{2}<1$, so $(2-\sqrt{2})^n\to 0$.  Note that $(2-\sqrt{2})^n=a_n-b_n\sqrt{2}$ for some integers $a_n,b_n$ by binomial theorem, so $$0<(2-\sqrt{2})^n=(a_n-2b_n)+b_n(2-\sqrt{2}).\tag{1}$$
If $2-\sqrt{2}$ were rational, say $=p/q$, $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$, then by equation (1) $(2-\sqrt{2})^n$ must be at least $1/q$, contradicting $(2-\sqrt{2})^n\to 0$.